# How to install ionic app in android device through terminal?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic android app and it generates the output apk file inside

```
project->platforms->android->build->outputs
```

Then inorder to test the app, i am forced to manually copy the apk file to my device to install app on it. So is there any way by which i can directly install the apk in my device  when i build the ionic project through terminal?  In android studio, the app get installed on the device when we run the project. I am looking for same kind of methode with ionic.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes its a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are running `ionic build android`.

You need to run the command `ionic run android`.
If your `ANDROID_HOME` path is correctly set, it will run in your connected device or if no device is connected, it will start your android emulator device.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run this command `ionic run android --device`. If your `ANDROID_HOME` path is correctly set, it will run in your connected device as well.